# How to Understand Time Complexity Expression for Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

Sorry this question might be a stupid one asked by a new programmer(myself:)). From the following link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-4-master-method-solving-recurrences/
Time complexity of merge sort is T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + cn

Here are my questions:

1. 2*T(n/2) represents the time spent on: "divide and conquer" process for the left part(from index 0 to index middle) and right part(from index middle+1 to the last element of n) of n inputs, is that right?
2. cn represents the time spent on: the "conquer" process for n inputs since we need to go through all the n inputs in order to put them in the right order, is that right?

Comment: Looks right to me. In fact that's how it concludes that it's in category 2, which gives you nlogn complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + cn is the relationship between an ideal time and the number of elements. In this case it applies to both top down and bottom up merge sort. It could be expressed as:

```
T(2m) = 2*T(m) + 2cm   (2c is a constant, so it could just be ... + cm)
```

So stating this with words, the time it takes to sort 2m elements is 2 x the time it takes to sort m elements plus the time it takes to merge 2m elements. For the merge part, the number of moves will always be 2m, but the number of compares will range from m to 2m-1.